# JavaScript Calendar Operations

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, calendar

I have Java code like that:

```
  //first moment of the today
  Calendar cal = new GregorianCalendar();
  cal.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
  cal.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

  Calendar tomorrow = (Calendar)cal.clone();
  tomorrow.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_YEAR, 1);

  long time = d.getTime();

  // if greater than today's first moment
  if(time >= tomorrow.getTimeInMillis()){
  ...
  }
  ...
```

How can I rewrite it with JavaScript?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var cal = new Date();
cal.setHours(0);
cal.setMinutes(0);
cal.setSeconds(0);
cal.setMilliseconds(0);

var tomorrow = new Date();

tomorrow.setDate(cal.getDate()+1);
```

i'm going to assume d is a date object you got from somewhere else:

```
if ( d >= tomorrow ) {

};
```

http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/jsref_obj_date.asp

Comment: Some extra documentation, just in case (and my preferred one for anything JS :-)): https://developer.mozilla.org/en/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: @Neves I am accepting it as an answer with your comment. Voting up your comment.